# Need Powershell command to avoid memory error

Tags: powershell

I need to update a file and remove any string that says "ENCRYPTED = YES", the below command works on a test file but the actual file is 250GB and it runs out of memory.  Is there a way to go through part of the file at a time and make the update?

(Get-Content -path "X:\file1.sql") -replace "`ENCRYPTED`=YES;", ";" | Set-Content -Path X:\file_updated.sql

Comment: @iRon, that doesn't work, it fails saying "Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'replace' .

Comment: Remove the brackets as it will choke the pipeline (read everything in memory) and replace the string in each line: `Get-Content -path "X:\file1.sql" |ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "ENCRYPTED=YES;", ";" } | Set-Content -Path X:\file_updated.sql`

Comment: Still didn't work, now it's saying "Set-Content : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

Comment: You probably need to quote the path: `-path "X:\file_updated.sql"`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be it.  It's running now and the memory isn't going up much at all.  Thank you!